# Creating an alias sometimes causes a 404 userkey not found when executing right after creating a user?

Tags: java, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api, google-app-engine

I've build a java webapplication (java/angular) in Google AppEngine using the Directory API. The goal is to create a user and immediately give it an alias.

Create user:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users
```

On a status 200 (user created) I do the following call:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/userKey/aliases
```

For the second call I'm getting a 404 most of the time. Sometimes it seems to work.

After creating the user I've tried doing a get request for the created user like this:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/userKey
```

This always works. Yet when doing the insert aliases request I'm still getting a 404.

It seems like the user isn't entirely created at the moment that the alias request is send.

What is the best way to deal this issue? Should I implement a sleep, a looping mechanism or am I overlooking something in the API?

I am using AppEngine v1.9.17 and google-api-services-admin-directory version directory_v1-rev47-1.19.0

Comment: Have you tried the sleep approach? if so, did it worked?

Comment: Yes, using sleep works but it doesn't seem like a clean solution.